# Snowflake SQL, Insert more than 1 row at a time using parameterised SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

So I am currently just trying to simply iterate through a for loop and bulk insert into snowflake the values, however it seems to be just running each query one at a time instead of bulking them together.

I've been looking at other solutions to using IDbCommand but none seem to work...

```
        //SnowflakeConnector snowflake = snowflakeCon;
        //IDbCommand snowCommand = snowflake.con.CreateCommand();
        try
        {

            IDbCommand cmd = snowflake.con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into TEST values (?)";
            //IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); // this crashes

            var p1 = cmd.CreateParameter();
            p1.ParameterName = "1";
            p1.Value = 10;
            p1.DbType = DbType.Int32;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);


            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                p1.Value = i;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // inserts one at a time instead of bulk
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

the documentation provided is a very basic example; https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-net

Comment: It's in the documentation.  To insert 3 rows you'd uses `VALUES (?), (?), (?)` and then bind 3 variables to it...

Comment: yes... I know... but these are predefined, obviously for a more realistic use case I would like to iterate through a dataset and insert dynamically.. is where I am struggling (I am no sql expert)

Comment: elaborating a bit more is... Is there not a better way than creating multiple instances of cmd.CreateParameter?

Comment: No, if you want to insert 100 rows you're going to create 100 parameter objects.  Ideally in an array, to be flexible.  Then to insert 1000 rows you could use the 100 row insert statement 10 times.  *(what the ideal batch size is for snowflake, I have no idea)*

Answer (score 0):

To add to the comments in this question, there are two suggestions I would make.

1. The recommended size for batch uploads to Snowflakes is 10 MB to 100 MB per file.
2. I looked at the Snowflake .NET connector documentation and see they you don't need a for loop to insert data, try this instead (from their documentation):

```
using (IDbConnection conn = new SnowflakeDbConnection())
{
    conn.ConnectionString = connectionString;
    conn.Open();

    IDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into t values (?),(?),(?)";
    IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    var p1 = cmd.CreateParameter();
    p1.ParameterName = "1";
    p1.Value = 10;
    p1.DbType = DbType.Int32;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);

    var p2 = cmd.CreateParameter();
    p2.ParameterName = "2";
    p2.Value = 10000L;
    p2.DbType = DbType.Int32;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p2);

    var p3 = cmd.CreateParameter();
    p3.ParameterName = "3";
    p3.Value = (short)1;
    p3.DbType = DbType.Int16;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p3);

    var count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Assert.AreEqual(3, count);             

    conn.Close();
}
```

From: https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-net

Answer (score 0):

I believe it still runs insert. If you want to do bulk insert, then you should use COPY command.